# Redirecting to an external page using JWT

Tags: apex, visualforce, jwt

I am required to redirect a user to an external payment gateway, from a visualforce page. Apart from just the redirection, sensitive information is to be passed to the external gateways, and using JWT.

As a proof of concept, I would need to understand how to store information in a JWT format in Saelsforce, and pass that JWT to an external website while redirecting.

Comment: Are you certain you have your terminology correct here? As far as I know, JWTs themselves don't do any redirection. Their primary use is in OAuth (to authenticate with some system). The response you get could include a url to redirect to, but using JWT (or any OAuth flow, really) generally means that you're going to perform a request on your user's behalf (so redirecting your user wouldn't make much sense).

Comment: In short: You need to re-evaluate the requirements you were given, or provide more information.

Comment: @DerekF, Yes actually. So, to sum up, ,the requirement is to redirect to a payment gateway. But, the information that we need to pass to the payment gateway, should be in a JWT format. I am completely new to JWT, and not aware about how can I embed information in JWT and pass information to the external site where I am redirecting to.

Its all from Salesforce to outside link.

Comment: Is this payment gateway a well known gateway with documentation that you can point us to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The information about how to store the information in a JWT in Salesforce is provided in the documentation of the JWT class [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_class_Auth_JWT.htm).

You may find the [JWTBearerTokenExchange](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_class_Auth_JWTBearerTokenExchange.htm#apex_class_Auth_JWTBearerTokenExchange) and [JWS](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_class_Auth_JWS.htm#apex_class_Auth_JWS) classes useful as well for your purpose

This video may be helpful for you too: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cViU2-xVscA